# Android with MobileServiceClient crashed on AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, azure-mobile-services

I've problem with:

```
public void GetNews() {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final List<News> results = newsTable.execute().get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        newsAdapter.clear();
                         for (News news : results) {
                            newsAdapter.add(news);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialog(e, "Chyba");
            }
             return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

App every crashed when executing this code :-(
Code get rows from table in azure mobile services.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Post Logcat stacktrace !

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your full code sample, my guess is that you've not initialized `newsAdapter` in a proper way and it is failing when adding there. Share your full code sample and error logs and I can try and be more specific.